# Invalid assignment to unsigned char C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I wrote the following but for some reason calling InstructionVal(b) is invalid.
intellisense is spitting out:

Only () is allowed for initializer member NPPInstructionDef::InstructionVal

here is the offending code:

```
//Single Instruction Definition for Instruction Dictionary
typedef struct NPPInstructionDef
{
    const char* InstructionName;
    const unsigned char* InstructionVal[];

     NPPInstructionDef(const char* a, const unsigned char* b[]): InstructionName(a), InstructionVal()
    {
    }
}NPPInstruction;
```

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming your initialization is `InstructionVal(
b )`, rather than the `InstructionVal()` which you've written.
But even then, what you've written shouldn't compile.

This is the usual problem, due to the fact that C style arrays
are broken, and shouldn't be used.  Your definition:

```
unsigned char const* InstructionVal[];
```

defines an array of unknown length (thus, illegal in a class
defintion) of `unsigned char*`.  There's no way to initialize
this in an initialization list, except by `()` (value
initialization).

What you want is:

```
std::vector <unsigned char*> InstructionVal;
```

, and the constructor should be:

```
NPPInstructionDef( std::string const& a,
                   std::vector <unsigned char> const& b );
```

, or perhaps more likely:

```
template <typedef Iterator>
NPPInstructionDef( std::string const& a,
                   Iterator begin,
                   Iterator end )
    : InstructionName( a )
    , InstructionDef( begin, end )
{
}
```

(This supposes, of course, that `InstructionName` is
`std::string`, instead of `char const*`.  Which will avoid any
issues of lifetime of the string, for example, and allow easy comparison, etc.)